# How to include bootstrap-vue icons into nuxtjs? Problem with navbar down arrows

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

Edit: hmm there might be a styling override - 
I can take the dropdown from below thats working. And stick it into the nav area and the down arrow disappears. Same can be said for the "lang" drop down, if i move it to the body, the arrow shows up..

EDIT: FML - it was another nav bar styles overriding, USE SCOPE LOL

Navbar svg downarrows won't show up. Most other icons are working just fine..The code below is pretty much copy and pasted for bootstrap vue exampe..

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" >
    <b-navbar-brand href="#"><img src="" class="d-inline-block align-top" width="220" height="45"></b-navbar-brand>

    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item href="#"></b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Home</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#">Contact Us</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#">FAQ</b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>

      <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
        <b-nav-item-dropdown  text="Lang" right>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
          <!-- Using 'button-content' slot -->
          <template v-slot:button-content>
            <em>Welcome, Friend</em>
          </template>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item href="#">Sign Out</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
```

Some icons work others don't.No errors are being throw.

The documentation says they are not installed by default...so I installed them with
https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/icons/

`npm i bootstrap-icons`

I created a plugin thats included nuxt.config.js. 
The elements all seem to be working correctly but the icons..

```
 plugins: [
  '@/plugins/bootstrap-vue.js'
  ,'@/plugins/mixins/user.js'
],
```

/plugins/bootstrap.vue.js below

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)
```

I also tried to include them specifically

```
import {BootstrapVue,BIconArrowUp, BIconArrowDown } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
import { BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Vue.component('BIconArrowUp', BIconArrowUp)
Vue.component('BIconArrowDown', BIconArrowDown)
```

1) I DON'T see any related to icons in the node_modules/bootstrap folder.

2) I DO see bootstrap.vue-icon.* in the node_modules/bootstrap-vue folder. It contains like -icons.common.js, -icons.css.

I ALso tried to add icons directly to the element like..

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown icon="circle-fill" text="Lang" right>
```

Here's a snip from bootstrap-vue site with the down arrow icons showing correctly. The very bottom photo is a snip of my project with the arrows missing..

[image: Icons working]

Here i added some of the other `<b>` components to my project to see if icons, arrows were working.And they do..

[image]
[image]


But for  b-navbar-dropdown.... They don't work!


[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: What version of BootstrapVue are you using? You don't need to add `bootstrap-icons` as a dependancy.  BootstrapVue's Icons are built from the source of bootstrap-icons before being published on NPM (as they are created as components).  Icons were added in BootstrapVue version v2.2.0, and the updated icons were added in BootstrapVue v2.8.0

Comment: Also note that the dropdown caret is _not_ an icon. It is created via CSS by Bootstrap v4.x's CSS/SCSS as a pseudo `::after` element.

Comment: BootstrapVue is the latest v2.10.1, and bootstrap v4.4.1, thats weird there must have been something going on. Because none of the <b-icons> would work until i added Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons) in my plugin

Answer (score 19):

According to the [official docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#icons), BootstrapVue does not install the icons plugin by default.

To enable this in Nuxt, edit your `nuxt.config.js`, find the `'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'` module in the `modules` array and change it from this:

```
modules: [
  'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',

  // ...other modules
]
```

to this, with inline configs:

```
modules: [
  'bootstrap-vue/nuxt', {
    icons: true
  }
]
```

or this if you want separate module configs:

```
modules: [
  'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
],

bootstrapVue: {
  icons: true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Soviut is mostly correct but the inline config option will not work but will throw a Nuxt Fatal Error. It only expects strings in the modules array. This solution does work however which is just creating an object for bootstrapVue specifying icons: true:

```
modules: [
  'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
],

bootstrapVue: {
  icons: true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to reduce your production bundle size I would recommend you to import specific icons.

```
module.exports = {
  modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt'],
  bootstrapVue: {
    components: ['BIcon', 'BIconAlertFill', 'BIconCalendar', 'BIconGears']
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can import BootstrapVueIcons like this:
first,edit bootstrap-vue.js file

[my nuxtjs project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCksC.png)
second,add this content in this file

```html
import Vue from 'vue';

import { BootstrapVue ,BootstrapVueIcons} from 'bootstrap-vue';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue, {});

Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons, {})
```

then you will get it.

Comment: The .nuxt folder is not intended to be checked in into version control. So any changes made here are not permanent.

Answer (score -1):

See the official docs for instructions on how to use bootstrap icons with nuxt.js
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#icons

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO.